# Using $all and match patterns

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB, each document contains an array called "tags" which is a distinct, lowercase array of strings. I have a distinct array of strings(called T from now on). My query finds every document which have a similar entry in it's "tags" array for every element in T.

This is the working query:

```
{
    "tags" : {
        "$all" : [
            /foo/,
            /bar/
        ]
    }
}
```

How could I execute this query from C#?

Here is the query I came up with:

```
return from item in items.AsQueryable()
       where T.All(t => item.Tags.Contains(t))
       select item;
```

This is almost what I want. The problem is that this uses equality operator, so the matching elements in item.Tags and T must be the same:

```
{
    "tags" : {
        "$all" : [
            "foo",
            "bar"
        ]
    }
}
```

My other attempt looked like this:

```
return from item in items.AsQueryable()
       where T.All(t => item.Tags.All(tag => tag.Contains(t))
       select item;
```

However this resulted in an unsupported operation exception, I guess because $regex inside $all is not allowed.

**Update:**

I could use FilterDefinition object and assign to it a string representation of my query. Is this the only way?